# NSDateFormatter giving me a NULL string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the following string:

```
"2012-12-06 21:55:00"
```

and when I put inside this:

```
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [df setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"];
```

it gives me null. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by "put inside"? Also when you say "gives me null" do you mean that `df` is `nil` after the inizialization?

Comment: Well, the date format you're setting isn't even close to the format of the date string you're feeding to the formatter.

Comment: When I pass in the string to the date formatter

Comment: what you want in output string or date??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need:

```
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

The date format needs to match the format of the date in the string.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the call to the `stringFromDate:` method of `NSDateFormatter`.

Also your custom format is not compliant with the example string you are providing, since it should be `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`

The proper way of achieving the result is

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate * yourDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:@"2012-12-06 21:55:00"];
```

Comment: There is no need to set the locale if you want the user's current locale.

Answer (score 0):

use this method to get `NSDate` from `NSString` date with your required format..

```
-(NSDate *)convertStringToDate:(NSString *) date {
        NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease]; 
        NSDate *nowDate = [[[NSDate alloc] init] autorelease];
        [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];// set format here which format in string date
        date = [date stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+0000" withString:@""];
        nowDate = [formatter dateFromString:date];
        return nowDate;
}
```

Get More info then see My Blog [Paras Joshi's Blog](http://parasjoshi3.blogspot.in/2012/01/convertstringtodatedatetostring.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have used following code. I tried it and it's working fine, you can try this code to find  difference between current time to another time.

```
NSTimer*  updateTimerValue=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1 target:self selector:@selector(DisplayTimer) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; 

-(void)DisplayTimer
{  
    NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
    [dateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"] autorelease]];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss "];
    NSDate *now = [[NSDate alloc] init];

    NSString *dt=[dateFormatter stringFromDate:now];


    NSDate* firstDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dt];
    NSDate* secondDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[_deale_detail_deal_endate_ary objectAtIndex:0]];

    NSTimeInterval timeDifference = [secondDate timeIntervalSinceDate:firstDate];

    int a=timeDifference;

    int m,s,h,d;
    m=a/60;
    s=a%60;
    h=m/60;
    m=m%60;
    d=h/24;
    h=h%24;
    s--;
    if (s<0) {
        m--;
        s=59;
    }
    if (m<0) {
        h--;
        m=59;
    }
    if (h<0) {
        d--;
        h=24;
    }

    //NSLog(@"%dd %dh %dm %ds",d,h,m,s);
    _deal_time_display_lbl.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%dd %dh %dm %ds",d,h,m,s];
}
```

Comment: you can check the NSnull condition .if (Nsstring name == [NSNull null])